# How Can I 301 Redirect All Old URLs

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I just updated my old shopping cart to a new one and I would like to know if some genius out there can give me an htaccess REWRITE rule that will redirect all of my old links to my new sites homepage.
Mainly, I want any link that begins with mySite.com/catalog to be redirected to the homepage. Please help!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1:**

You can use this rule as **first rule** in your `DocumentRoot/.htacess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^catalog(/|$) /? [L,NC,R=301]
```

**Option 2:**

You can use this rule as **first rule** in your `/catalog/.htacess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /catalog/
RewriteRule ^ /? [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: No, that didn't work. See the following link... it still does not redirect to DoralMedical.com  http://www.doralmedical.com/catalog/index.php?cPath=61&osCsid=66792101e2543fd563a96306dc2c9e8b

Comment: I guess that I should make it clear that I need to redirect any url that begins with doralmedical/catalog to doralmedical.com , This would mean that files or directories within /catalog would resolve to doralmedical.com. I think the previously posted rewrite rule only applies to files within the /catalog directory.

Comment: ok see updated code. Remember it goes into `/catalog/.htacess` file

Comment: @anubhava The problem here is that you are assuming the `catalog` directory still exists. Why keep that directory around unnecessarily?

Comment: Provided both options to OP. And no I am not assuming anything, you can read OP's previous comment.

Comment: @Mike_Brant The catalog directory still exist.

Comment: I updated my htaccess file with the code below and it not only does not redirect old urls but it also prevents the homepage from loading.    RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /catalog/
RewriteRule ^ /? [L,R=301]

Comment: Okay. I put an htaccess file into the /catalog directory with the rules that "anubhava" gave me and everything is working fine. Thank you so much gentlemen  :)

Comment: Hey Anubhava, I have a problem with the code that you gave me yesterday. I've discovered that its causing redirect and page load errors within the new code. Remember, I said that I changed shopping cart programs and both have a /catalog directory. Now, what I need is to modify the 301 redirect to redirect any link that begins with http://www.doralmedical.com/catalog/product_info.php? and have it redirect to the site's homepage. This should handle any already indexed links that are floating around on the internet. Please help!!

Comment: **In the option 2 rule:** use this rule: `RewriteRule ^product_info\.php /? [L,NC,R=301]`

Answer (score 0):

This should be as simple as placing the following in your Apache config or in .htaccess of web root directory.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?catalog/? / [L,R=301]
```